# How can I integrate this equation? (to get surface area of the mobius strip)

Tags: integration, derivatives, surface-integrals

[image]
I'm in the process of calculating surface area of the Mobius strip. I've derived the surface element so far and I got the equation above. Now, I need to integrate in terms of $s$ and in terms of $t$ (or I can integrate in terms of $t$ first and then $s$). However, I'm facing some difficulties that how can I transform or possibly substitute the equation in the form that can be integrated. Help me.

Comment: Note the surface repeats itself when $t\in [2\pi, 4\pi] $, you should integrate $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: A Mobius strip is just a rectangular strip with two sides attached in a unconventional way, hence its surface can be computed by just computing the area of a rectangle!

Comment: @NgChungTak But I thought the interval from 0 to 2\pi will produce the whole Mobius strip, which is the non-orientable surface, thus it is impossible to apply the surface integral. So I thought I'd better do the definite integral from 0 to \pi and double the result to get the total surface area. Is this right?

Comment: Have you ever tried to plot it?  See the details from equation (1) to (3) in [THIS LINK](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusStrip.html)

Comment: See my [PLOT](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QO30j.jpg) with $(s,t) \in [-1,1] \times [0,\pi]$.

Comment: @NgChungTak Yeah I've plotted it and as you said my interval will give half of the whole Mobius strip. But in this case, I'm doing the 'surface integral', which is known as impossible to be applied on the non-orientable surface with my knowledge. So I deliberately put the half interval. Is my logic right?

Comment: Non-orientable surface has jumping/discontinuity of normal vector.  Your integrand is in absolute value.  Imagine you **paint** a mobius strip, you only **paint** only half the surface in one turn, so all together you need $[0,4\pi]$.  See the animation [HERE](https://plus.maths.org/issue26/features/mathart/Twist.gif) and also [THIS](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/bagelrings.html).  Hence you should think carefully about what sort of areas you are talking about, that is the area to paint (opague surface with thickness) versus area of the framework (transparent surface or zero thickness).

Comment: @NgChungTak SO you mean I can do the integration directly from 0 to 4π not doing each segments separately and then sum up to get the surface area because it is in the absolute form?

Comment: Yes, conceptually for the painting case.  Of course, $\int_{0}^{4\pi} = 2\int_{0}^{2\pi}$ numerically.

Comment: @NgChungTak Can I ask again to make the concept sure? Is it really possible to apply the 'surface integral' from 0 to 4pi for t for the painting case even though graphically the surface repeat itself when it goes beyond 2pi?

Comment: Though the surface repeats itself for $t\in [2\pi,4\pi]$, the normal vectors are in opposite sense.  Referring back to the [previous gif](https://plus.maths.org/issue26/features/mathart/Twist.gif), you paint the orange side (with arrows) for $t\in [0,2\pi]$ and green side (without arrows) for $t\in [2\pi, 4\pi]$.

Comment: @NgChungTak Does that mean I need to explain the mobius strip as a vector field, in this application? As it needs to regard the opposite normal vectors? Or as a scalar field as you said earlier that my integral is in absolute form?

Comment: @NgChungTak You mean I should use surface integral for scalar field? or vector field? To regard the normal vector as you said, I should use the vector one, is this right?

Comment: The surface area is scalar whereas normal vector is vector.

Comment: @NgChungTak Yes the surface area is scalar but there are two types of surface integral, which is a way to calculate that surface area and one type is for vector field and one type is for scalar field. I mean which type of surface integral would be appropriate to explain this problem.

Comment: The numerical values of the integrand $\sqrt{\ldots}$ don't have sex.  The normal vector is used for checking the orientability that governs your limits of integration.

Comment: @NgChungTak That integrand I put above is derived from the scalar surface integral, as it is done before I got your comment and started to think about this 'normal vector issue' so it is scalar of course. Is it still possible to use the normal vector in the process of explanation even I use the scalar surface integral in the derivation? Or do you suggest me to apply the vector surface integral concept. But the problem here is normally people think mobius is non orientable so the vector integral is impossible

Comment: There's no physical meaning for $\iint \mathbf{x}_s \times \mathbf{x}_t \, ds \, dt$.  In fact, both $A(s,t)$ and $\mathbf{N}(s,t)$ are of parameter space, so they are not fields at all.

Comment: Note that $\mathbf{x}(s,t)=\mathbf{x}(s,t+2\pi)$ but $\mathbf{N}(s,t)=-\mathbf{N}(s,t+2\pi)$, that's why it's non-orientable.  Also, $\mathbf{N}(\mathbf{x})$ is not well-defined, therefore it's not a vector field.

Comment: @NgChungTak Your comment made me more definite. Actually, I'm a highschool student writing a paper about this issue and there is no one I can ask this question around me but you helped me a lot. So to sum up, I'll first explain the mobius strip's non orientability, but for computing its surface area I should go up to 4pi and the normal vector is well defined and opposite in each interval, which is 0 to 2pi and 2pi to 4pi, thus I can straightforwardly apply the scalar surface integral from 0 to 4pi. Does this process look right?

Comment: @NgChungTak Also, can I ask what do you mean by 'there's no physical meaning for scalar surface integral' in your last comment? I think that's the key reason why I can use the scalar surface integral in this case but still I feel difficulty in explaining that in my own words.

Comment: **BEHOLD!** $\iint \mathbf{x}_s \times \mathbf{x}_t \,ds \, dt$ is a vector that has no physical signficance and $A=\iint |\mathbf{x}_s \times \mathbf{x}_t| \,ds \, dt$ is the surface area.  Like Gauss' Law $\displaystyle \oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{A}=\frac{Q_\text{enclosed}}{\epsilon_0}$ but there's no physical meaning for $\oint \mathbf{E} \, dA$.

Comment: @NgChungTak Back again, can I ask why does having opposite normal vector does not limit my integration? I got your point generally, but I don't know what is the Mathematics under it that the opposite normal vector does not limit the scalar surface integral.

Comment: I think it's better for you to have **face-to-face consultation with your teacher**.  It's not effective to clarify everything for you here because I didn't know your background and curriculum.  And the discussion is far more beyond your original question.  Or you may **post a new question** and **point out clearly** what you need to know.  You may look up some books concerning **Multi-variable Calculus** and **Differential Geometry** for your own sake.  Good luck!